# How to gradient border in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello does anyone tell me how to add border gradient in react native i know that for linear gradient we use `react-native-linear-gradient` package but for border how can we achive that.

this is code that i try

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {console.warn('gradient')})}>
  <LinearGradient colors={['#000', '#fff']}>
    <View style={styles.circleGradient}>
      <Text style={styles.visit}>Gradient Border</Text>
    </View>
  </LinearGradient>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to make a LinearGradient and then absolutely position your content over it, making your content just slightly smaller than the gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {console.warn('gradient')})}>
  <LinearGradient colors={['rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)', '#fff']} locations={[0.7, 1]}>
    <View style={styles.circleGradient}>
      <Text style={styles.visit}>Gradient Border</Text>
    </View>
  </LinearGradient>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

You can play with this ***[0.7, 1]*** to set the gradient location